# How to combine '-i file' & '-O filename' options of wget?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, wget

`wget` can be feeded with `-i inputFileURLList` and also can use a custom file name with `-O customArbitraryFileName`.

How can I combine these two capablities so that I feed it with a file containig URL list with a custom file name for each?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write your own trivial shell script and use it as `./get-them.sh < get-then.list`

shell script `get-them.sh`

```
#!/bin/sh
while read FILE URL; do
   wget -O "$FILE" -- "$URL"
done
```

input file `get-them.list`

```
file1 https://unix.stackexchange.com/
file2 https://stackexchange.com/
```

Comment: How would you write this using $1 for the input file?

Comment: @KenIngram `done < $1`

Comment: Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the input file looks like

```
http://url.to.import
file.to.save.as
```

to process the input file once:

```
{ IFS= read -r url; IFS= read -r filename; } < input.file
wget -i "$url" -O "$filename"
```

I'm using curly braces so the read commands are performed in the current shell, and thus the variables exist in the current shell.

If you desperately need a one-liner

```
wget -i "$(sed -n 1p input.file)" -O "$(sed -n 2p input.file)"
```